# Extrude object along curve not working

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, extrude

I'm trying to create a series of arches based on a single molding profile. I've created each arch as a curve and the plan was to then take the profile (a single face at the moment) and extrude it along the curve to create the arch I want. However, something I can't even explain is happening and the extrusion is not conforming to the curve. I've also tried extruding first and then attaching a curve modifier and get the same result.

[image]

If it will help, you can download my blender file here.
http://www.mediafire.com/?27kos3cwfkf2c

Let me know what I've done wrong and thanks in advance!

Comment: it works, you have to deactivate the snap option, extrude your shape, give it an Array modifier that you put above the Curve modifier, choose the bezier curve as the Object of the Curve modifier, apply the rotation of the curve, find the right Deformation axis and rotation for your object... you could also convert your object into a bezier and then select your arch and choose the profil as the Bevel Object in the Data panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not sure what technique you are using to "extrude along a curve".  The array modifier is one way to do it as moonboots mentions.  Another one, which I used to create the image below, is to convert your profile mesh to a curve, then use it as the "Bevel Object" of your arch form curve.  You can then convert the resulting curve to a mesh (as I've done with a duplicate in the screenshot).  You will need to be sure to apply location, rotation, and scale to your objects, INCLUDING the arch curve object, to get this to work right, and even after that you may need to rotate the profile (and apply the rotation) so that the right bits are pointing in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how to rotate the profile? I selected the profile curve, rotate it several different ways, hit enter and nothing happened. I then went to the arch curve and deleted the bevel object and reconnected. It is still terribly twisted and upside down.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8mJ1omO

Comment: Did you try applying the rotation?  Object-->Apply-->Rotation, or Ctrl-A-->Rotation.  You need to do this each time you rotate.  You also need to apply the rotation of the arch curve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bevel Object option under the Curve Properties for each arc. In your case you must first convert your profile (a mesh) in a curve, the shortcut is <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Then select one of the arcs, and choose the name of the profile in the Bevel Object option.

[image: Bevel Arches]